# MVC Can't Find Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC 4 app in which i am wanting to use the web api to get my data. EDIT- this is a Single Page Application that started out with the Hot Towel Template.  The problem is that I get the 404 resource not found when i try to call the controller from JSON.  Here is my Controller-

```
 Public Class CAApprovalController
     Inherits ApiController

     Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
         Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
    End Function
 End Class
```

Here is my JSON call-

```
 function getallCertificates() {
     $.getJSON('api/CAApproval', function (data) {
         allCertificates([]);
         var temp = allCertificates();
         data.forEach(function (p) {
             var certificate = new Certificate(p.ClientID, p.RequestDate, p.UserName,                  p.StatusDescription,             p.StatusCode, p.StatusDesc, p.CEOUserName);
             temp.push(certificate);
         });
         allCertificates.valueHasMutated();
         return allCertificates();
     });
 }
```

Here is the webapiconfig-

```
Public Class WebApiConfig
        Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
                name:="DefaultApi", _
                routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
                defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
        )


    'To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
    'For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
    config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing()

    'Use camel case for JSON data.
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = New CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
End Sub
End Class
```

I am new to MVC and especially web api, and am thinking it is a newbie issue.  Just not sure what the problem is.  Is there a configuration or something i am missing?  The project was created as a MVC 4 / web api application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem at last. Turns out that Breezejs was the problem. My app is a single page application, and Breeze was one of the components of my SPA app (Breeze was installed as part of the Hot Towel template i was using). Not sure why, but when i uninstalled Breeze, the controllers i added to the project became visible. Something in the breeze scripts hi-jack the api routing.

Comment: We found the same thing.  Any idea how to add "api/{controller}/{id}" route without removing Breeze?

Answer (score 0):

You realize that "api/..." means "from the current relative location" right?

You probably want "/api/..." in your ajax call.

EDIT:

It's better to use a Url Helper.

```
$.getJSON('@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "CAApproval" })', function (data) {
```

Comment: I did try that as well.  Still, when looking in Chrome, I still get the resource not found.

Comment: @Chris - Is this project at the root?  Or is it in a subfolder of the root?

Comment: @Chris, Well, you need to use the full path in your ajax request.

Comment: I have a solution folder, under which i created the MVC web application.  So, the solution folder is called LucasNetSolution, and the web app is LucasNetApp.  the controller is named CAApprovalController.  So, if i wanted to try this in the web browser, what url would i use then?

Comment: side note, the caapprovalcontroller is in a folder called controllers.  If i understand it correctly, the location of the controller within the project does not matter, right?

Comment: @Chris - According to your code, it's CertificateController, not CAApprovalController.  And no, the controllers location is unimportant because it's compiled into code.

Comment: That was a typo.  it should have read CAApprovalController.  Will edit.

Comment: I set breakpoints in the controller.  From the Json call, it should have found the controller, but it does not.  Chrome also confirms it is not finding the controller.

Comment: I get internal server error from that.  still does not hit breakpoints either.  details of the error say - Illegal characters in path

Comment: @Chris - are you using the HttpRouteUrl?  I updated it after initially posting it.

Comment: I just updated and tried again, this time using the httpRouteUrl.  Still get internal server error, Illegal characters in path

Comment: @Chris - You mean in the ajax call?  What is the URL that it's generating?

Comment: function getallCertificates() {
        $.getJSON('@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "CAApproval" })', function (data) {
            allCertificates([]);
            var temp = allCertificates();
            data.forEach(function (p) {
                var certificate = new Certificate(p.ClientID, p.RequestDate, p.UserName, p.StatusDescription, p.StatusCode, p.StatusDesc, p.CEOUserName);
                temp.push(certificate);
            });
            allCertificates.valueHasMutated();
            return allCertificates();
        });
    }

Comment: Found the problem at last.  Turns out that Breezejs was the problem.  My app is a single page application, and Breeze was one of the components of my SPA app (Breeze was installed as part of the Hot Towel template i was using).  Not sure why, but when i uninstalled Breeze, the controllers i added to the project became visible.  Something in the breeze scripts hi-jack the api routing.  Thanks for the time you spent on my behalf Mystere Man.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting your web api in IIS or running it from Visual Studio. If IIS, /LucasNetApp/api/caaproval. If Visual Studio, /api/caaproval.

Comment: I am running local development server within Visual Studio.  /api/caaproval does not find it.

Comment: My answer has a typo. /api/caapproval should work. Type `http://localhost:<port>/api/caapproval` in the address bar of IE and see if it can get a JSON back. If that works, jQuery must work as well.

Comment: still got the resource not found

Comment: Sorry, no clue. If you have a controller class inside the controllers folder say xyzcontroller that derives from ApiController, with the routeTemplate of "api/{controller}/{id}", HTTP GET to the uri /api/xyz must map to the public scoped action method with name starting Get and without any parameters. Only suggestion I have is to see the VS Output window and see if the web API trace can give you any insights. I see that you already have tracing enabled.

Comment: Thanks Badri.  I will keep looking.